# How to split the address_street variable in PayPal IPN?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to get the correct address information passed back via IPN. I'm passing all the address variables through to PayPal (including address2) and using address_override=1 to ensure this address is used. This works fine. Address1 and address2 are obviously passed back concatenated within address_street and i want to separate these out again but they seem to just be separated by a space (which i obviously can't use to split it as there are probably multiple spaces). I've read other posts saying that %0D%0A or \r are used to split them up but that doesn't seem to be true for me (i've tried splitting with them and when i use $test_street = isset($_POST['address_street']) ? $_POST['address_street'] : ''; at the top of my ipn script and save $test_street in a db it just comes back with a space in between).

It seems ridiculously difficult to find out how these are joined and how to separate them, surely this can be an unusual thing to want? Obviously the workaround is to not use the address2 variable at all and just add it's contents to the end of the address1 variable with a comma inbetween but this means that it's not over 2 lines (and i don't have access to them as separate variables) which is quite annoying.

If anyone has any pointers as to how i can overcome this then it would be much appreciated as I can't work it out!

Thanks so much,

Dave

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
You can split it by `\r`.

```
list($address_street_line1, $address_street_line2) = explode("\r", $_POST['address_street']);
```